# Issue with Python implementation of Kruskal's maze algorithm

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, maze

I decided to make a variable-size binary tree maze generator.  I am trying to use Kruskal's maze algorithm, and I need to create a program that sees if there is a way for the player to get from cell x to cell y.  I was having trouble figuring out the maze solving.  I decided to implement a maze solver into the binary tree generator, and I have the basics but it's having some issues I can't figure out.

It starts in the middle of the first cell then randomly chooses a direction and tries to go forward to where the wall may or may not be, and if it isn't a possible move it tries again in another random direction.  Since I made the spaces in the walls simply but drawing them over in white, I had to create a list of every acceptable wall to pass through.

My current issue is that it cannot go vertically twice for some reason, but it (usually) has no problem going horizontally twice.  Any ideas?

```
from turtle import *
import random

def online(y,z):
  first = z[0]
  second = z[1]
  firstx = first[0]
  firsty = first[1]
  secondx = second[0]
  secondy = second[1]
  if firstx <= y[0] <= secondx and firsty >= y[1] >= secondy:
    return(True)
  elif firstx <= y[0] <= secondx and firsty <= y[1] <= secondy:
    return(True)
  elif firstx >= y[0] >= secondx and firsty >= y[1] >= secondy:
    return(True)
  elif firstx <= y[0] <= secondx and firsty >= y[1] >= secondy:
    return(True)

speed(0)
gridsize = 4
cellsize = 50
hideturtle()

cango = []

for i in range(4):
  a = pos()
  forward(gridsize*cellsize)
  b = pos()
  x = (a,b)
  left(90)
goto(0,0)
for i in range(gridsize):
  forward(cellsize)
  left(90)
  a = pos()
  forward(gridsize*cellsize)
  b = pos()
  x = (a,b)
  forward(-gridsize*cellsize)
  seth(0)
goto(0,0)
seth(90)
for i in range(gridsize):
  forward(cellsize)
  right(90)
  a = pos()
  forward(gridsize*cellsize)
  b = pos()
  x = (a,b)
  forward(-gridsize*cellsize)
  seth(90)
  
color("white")
pensize(2)
seth(270)
a = pos()
forward(cellsize)
b = pos()
x = (a,b)
forward(-cellsize)
seth(0)


choices = (1,2)
for i in range(gridsize):
  choices = (1,2) #Choice 1 cuts the right wall and choice 2 cuts the bottom wall
  for i in range(gridsize):
    a = int(pos()[0])
    b = int(pos()[1])
    #if the x value is all the way on the right, force the choice to cut the bottom
    if a == (gridsize-1)*cellsize or a == (gridsize-1)*cellsize-1:
      x = 2
    #if the y value is all the way on the bottom, force the choice to cut the right
    elif b == cellsize or b == cellsize-1:
      x = 1
    else:
    #if not at x or y max choose randomly between cutting right and cutting down
      x = random.choice(choices)
    #cut right
    if x == 1:
      penup()
      seth(0)
      forward(cellsize)
      right(90)
      pendown()
      a = pos()
      forward(cellsize)
      b = pos()
      x = a,b
      cango.append(x)
      forward(-cellsize)
      seth(0)
    #cut bottom
    elif x == 2:
      penup()
      seth(270)
      forward(cellsize)
      seth(0)
      pendown()
      a = pos()
      forward(cellsize)
      b = pos()
      x = a,b
      cango.append(x)
      penup()
      seth(90)
      forward(cellsize)
      seth(0)
  penup()
  seth(180)
  forward(cellsize*gridsize)
  seth(270)
  forward(cellsize)
  seth(0)
speed(3)
showturtle()
color("red")
goto(25,175)
penup()
print(cango)
pensize(4)
for i in range(1000):
    if pos() == (175.0,0.0):
        pensize(10)
        pencolor("green")
        break
    direction = random.randint(1,4)
    penup()
    if direction == 1:
        seth(0)
    elif direction == 2:
        seth(90)
    elif direction == 3:
        seth(180)
    else:
        seth(270)
    penup()
    forward(25)
    nohit = True
    for i in cango:
      if online(pos(),i) == True:
          nohit = False
      x = i[0]
      y = i[1]
      #if x[0] == pos()[0] and x[1] == pos()[1] or y[0] == pos()[0] and y[1] == pos()[1]:
        #nohit = True
    if nohit == False:
      backward(25)
      pendown()
      forward(50)
    else:
      backward(25)
```

---

#### Solved

If anyone runs into similar problems, my issue came from the fact that python turtle isn't 100% accurate when defining points, due to this my points were sometimes things like (24.999999991,100) and I ended up forcing them to be integers and for my program I was only working with multiples of 5's so for every point I tested if anything was a 4 or a 9 and if so I added 1.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Why you can't move horizontally twice?

Comment: Yeah sorry I wasn't very clear.  I can't figure out why it works the first time then can't move again

Comment: I may have figured it out, i think it's because I used the variable "i" for a loop and a loop nested in it which messed it up, working on fixing it now because that presented other errors

Comment: Hey @jacksoncyr - welcome to StackOverflow.  FYI: I have edited your question to include only the essentials needed to describe the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

> python turtle isn't 100% accurate when defining points, due to this my
>   points were sometimes things like (24.999999991,100)

You have to change your thinking.  The turtle wanders a floating point plane.  All floating point implementations have compromises.  Learn to deal with them:

> I ended up forcing them to be integers ... for every point I tested if anything was a 4 or a 9 and if so I added 1

I'd suggest `round()`, rather than your combination of `int()` and testing both above and below.  But a better approach is to use subtraction, or `turtle.distance()`, and check if the difference is small enough to call it the same.

Here's my rework of your code using the above approach; fixing issues to allow the grid to be resized; style and optimization changes.  See if these modifications make sense to you:

```
from turtle import *
from random import randrange, choice

GRID_SIZE = 5
CELL_SIZE = 50
RIGHT, BOTTOM = 1, 2  # Choice 1 cuts the right wall and choice 2 cuts the bottom wall

def online(position, line):

    x, y = position

    (firstx, firsty), (secondx, secondy) = line

    if firstx <= x <= secondx and firsty >= y >= secondy:
        return True
    if firstx <= x <= secondx and firsty <= y <= secondy:
        return True
    if firstx >= x >= secondx and firsty >= y >= secondy:
        return True
    if firstx <= x <= secondx and firsty >= y >= secondy:
        return True

    return False

# Draw the grid

hideturtle()
speed('fastest')

for _ in range(GRID_SIZE):
    forward(CELL_SIZE)
    left(90)
    forward(GRID_SIZE * CELL_SIZE)
    backward(GRID_SIZE * CELL_SIZE)
    right(90)

home()
setheading(90)

for _ in range(GRID_SIZE):
    forward(CELL_SIZE)
    right(90)
    forward(GRID_SIZE * CELL_SIZE)
    backward(GRID_SIZE * CELL_SIZE)
    left(90)

# Undraw walls to create a maze

color('white')
setheading(270)

forward(CELL_SIZE)
backward(CELL_SIZE)
setheading(0)

cango = []

for _ in range(GRID_SIZE):

    for i in range(GRID_SIZE):
        a, b = position()

        # if the x value is all the way on the right, force the choice to cut the bottom
        if abs(((GRID_SIZE - 1) * CELL_SIZE) - a) < CELL_SIZE / 4:
            wall = BOTTOM
        # if the y value is all the way on the bottom, force the choice to cut the right
        elif abs(CELL_SIZE - b) < CELL_SIZE / 4:
            wall = RIGHT
        else:
            # if not at x nor y max, choose randomly between cutting right and cutting down
            wall = choice([RIGHT, BOTTOM])

        penup()

        if wall == RIGHT:  # cut right
            setheading(0)
            forward(CELL_SIZE)
            right(90)
            pendown()
            start = position()
            forward(CELL_SIZE)
            end = position()

        elif wall == BOTTOM:  # cut bottom
            setheading(270)
            forward(CELL_SIZE)
            setheading(0)
            pendown()
            start = position()
            forward(CELL_SIZE)
            end = position()
            right(90)

        cango.append((start, end))
        penup()
        backward(CELL_SIZE)
        setheading(0)

    penup()
    backward(CELL_SIZE * GRID_SIZE)
    setheading(270)
    forward(CELL_SIZE)
    setheading(0)

#  Solve the maze

speed('slow')
shape('turtle')
color('red')
pensize(4)
goto(CELL_SIZE / 2, GRID_SIZE * CELL_SIZE - CELL_SIZE / 2)
showturtle()

change_heading = False  # get the most you can out of a direction change

while pencolor() == 'red':

    if distance(GRID_SIZE * CELL_SIZE - CELL_SIZE / 2, -CELL_SIZE / 2) <= CELL_SIZE / 4:
        color('green')
        break

    penup()

    if change_heading:
        direction = randrange(4) * 90
        setheading(direction)
        change_heading = False

    forward(CELL_SIZE / 2)

    nohit = True

    for line in cango:
        if online((round(xcor()), round(ycor())), line):
            nohit = False
            break

    backward(CELL_SIZE / 2)

    if not nohit:
        pendown()
        forward(CELL_SIZE)
    else:
        change_heading = True

mainloop()
```

[image]